# Spring MVC и потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, spring-mvc

И так. Есть проект. Платформа для прохождения различных тестов. Тесты могут быть ограниченны по времени как самим юзером так и дефолтным значением(время в данном случае это промежуток в течении которого юзверь может через форму ответов пробрасывать выбранные варианты ответа). Встал вопрос как реализовать сервис. 
А именно:
Имеется сервис который приняв юзверя и тест создает из внутреннего класса "Таймер" поток который в свою очередь существует на протяжении какого то времени(которое либо задаётся дефолтно либо возьмется из сущности теста как заданный юзверем параметр). Соответственно калькуляция результата может произойти в двух случаях: закончится время или пользователь ответит на все вопросы.
НО: надо предусмотреть ситуацию когда Юзер перезашел на страницу и попытался продолжить проходить тест/перепройти по новой пока еще текущий поток существует.
Теоретическое решение: создать в сервисе лист потоков который будет самоподчищаться от неактивных потоков и через который будет проверятся "а не начал ли юзверь пытаться проходить тест заново?".
И вот тут возник вопрос: Как работают сервисы в Spring? Т.е. один сервис работает со всеми клиентами / под каждого клиента создается свой сервис / под каждую сессию создается свой сервис. Потому что от этого зависит будут ли вообще новые потоки таймера добавляться в лист Сервиса или же будет ситуация когда один сервис не сможет содержать больше одного потока. Как в таком случае следует конструировать задуманное?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, для реализации этого функционала потоки вообще не нужны. Достаточно сохранить в базу время начала прохождения теста конкретным пользователем и проверять сколько прошло при каждом обращении к контроллерам. Можно для такой проверки аспект написать. Во-вторых, сервис - это бин. По умолчанию все бины - это синглтоны. При желании можно сервис с областью видимости запроса создать, только незачем в данном случае.